# CustomTitleBar keeps getting reset to a huge height when reloading the program into Rad Studio

Tags: delphi

I have a small application which uses the Custom Title bar.  In use I have no issues with it, but each time I reload the program into Delphi the title bar has grown in height covering everything else and has to be returned manually to the required height.

I saw this effect when running my code until I set the height in the resize event.

Is this normal operation or have I missed something?

Comment: IMMNSHO, if you care about quality and don't like buggy software, you should stay miles away from custom title bars and VCL styles.

Comment: Are you refering to [`TTitleBar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TTitleBar) or to [`TForm.CustomTitleBar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.CustomTitleBar)?

Comment: TForm.CustomTitleBar / TTitleBarPanel

Answer (score 1):

I have found that setting the CustomTitleBar.SystemHeight to true resolves problem because my controls fit within the system Toolbar height.

I guess the issue remains if you want to extent the Toolbar height.